# DataTables search on specific columns

Tags: jquery, datatables, jquery-select2

I have adapted the following webpage to my needs and added a bit of code so it now has select2 dropdown menus instead of regular select menus (which I like a LOT better). However I have not been able to figure out how to adapt the code so I can use it only on specific columns instead of on every column. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

http://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html (code I adapted)

```
initComplete: function () {
        this.api().columns().every( function () {
            var column = this;
            var select = $("<select class='searchs2'><option value=''></option></select>")
                .appendTo( $(column.header()).append() )
                .on( 'change', function () {
                    var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                        $(this).val()
                    );
                    column
                        .search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false )
                        .draw();
                } );
            column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) 
            { select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )});
        });
        $(".searchs2").select2();
    }
```

Also - if there is an option to hide the 'generic' search box I would like to hide it on top as well and just provide these select2 boxes. Thank you.

(edited to update the fix so select2 would initialize for every dropdown box, last one was not initializing)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `columns([array])`.  Instead of

```
this.api().columns().every( function () {
```

and you want to perform the search on the column 1,2,5 and 6 only :

```
this.api().columns([1,2,5,6]).every( function () {
```

Comment: I modified `this.api().columns().every( function () {` to `this.api().columns([1,2,5,6], function () {` (and several other variations) and I cannot get the syntax to initialize. this definitely seems like the solution. I'm going to have to tinker around with it a bit to get it working.

Comment: @JeffBSoloWookie, I think what David meant was that instead of this `this.api().columns().every( function () {` use this `this.api().columns([1,2,5,6]).every( function () {`.

Comment: ok - your edit was a 'little too simple'...  can't believe I did not see that :( (I did not think I could use the array with 'every' still in place)

Comment: as a side note on this; I noticed my very last dropbox box was not a select2 box. I had to move the location of `$(".searchs2").select2();` for the last one to initialize. I will modify the original post to reflect it.